# How to include total count of records using values from query results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I am running a query that returns the results seen below:

```
SELECT t1.col_a, t2.doc_id, t1.col_c
FROM dbo.table1 t1
LEFT JOIN dbo.table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.col_c = 'test'


########### RESULTS #########
| col_a |  doc_id |  col_c  |
-----------------------------
|content|    1    |    test |
|content|    2    |    test |
|content|    3    |    test |
```

**Sample Data**

This is an example of data I am working with:

```
############### TABLE 1 #######################
|   col_a  |  col_b  |   col_c  | id
---------------------------------------
| content  | content | test     |  22
| content  | content | test     |  23
| content  | content | asdf     |  24
| content  | content | test     |  25
| content  | content | asdf     |  26
| content  | content | qwer     |  27
| content  | content | asdf     |  28
| content  | content | test     |  29


############### TABLE 2 #######################
| t2_col_a |   doc_id  | t2_col_b| t2_col_c | id
-----------------------------------------------
| content  |     1     | content | content  | 22
| content  |     2     | content | content  | 23
| content  |     3     | content | content  | 24
| content  |     3     | content | content  | 25
| content  |     3     | content | content  | 26
| content  |     1     | content | content  | 27
| content  |     2     | content | content  | 28
| content  |     2     | content | content  | 29
```

What I would like to do is include a `COUNT` of **all** `doc_id`'s located in `table2`. For example:

```
######## DESIRED RESULTS ##########
| col_a |  doc_id | col_c | count |
------------------------------------
|content|    1    |  test |   2   |
|content|    2    |  test |   3   |
|content|    3    |  test |   3   |
```

I want to count all the records that are associated with each `doc_id` found in initial results (for example, there may be 500 records in `table2` that have a `doc_id` of `1`). The records I want to get a count of are found in `table2`.

I tried simply adding `COUNT (id)` after my `SELECT` statement, but that just returns `1` for each row, because it's counting the results from the query. How do I get the **total** count of records for each `doc_id` from `table2` within my query?

Comment: Very unclear, please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results.

Comment: I made edits to my post

Comment: You're still not showing your starting sample data... so its unclear exactly what you are counting... we need to see the sample data that your query is operating on.

Comment: Added some sample data. Does that help?

Comment: What about table1?

Comment: Also consider matching your current query according to the data you're making available at this time.

Comment: Okay, added example of table 1 as well.

Comment: Just adding a `COUNT(*)` and a `GROUP BY` would appear to solve your problem - similar to the first answer below, but count instead of sum.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work. When I added `COUNT(*)` in my `SELECT` statement, my query says there is a count of 1 for the `doc_id` 2, for example. When I query `table2` for `doc_id='2'`, there is way more than 1 record with that `doc_id`.

Comment: Please provide a dbfiddle which shows that, because with the data provided that would not happen.

Comment: Are you saying that even though your `WHERE` clause says `t1.col_c = 'test'` that you want to count all rows regardless of whether `t1.col_c = 'test'`?

Comment: Sorry, didn't have access to a computer. That is exactly what I'm trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

Is col_b stored as an integer? IF so, SUM() will do the trick. It might work with a varchar too but will be less efficient. Something like this:

```
SELECT t1.col_a, SUM(t2.col_b)
FROM dbo.table1 t1
LEFT JOIN dbo.table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.col_c = 'value'
GROUP BY t1.col_a
```

If you are not aware you will need to add the GROUP BY to use SUM for columns not in the SUM.